# How to tell the screen display is a view of a launcher or other app?

Tags: android

I want to know the content of the current screen display is created by a launcher or other app, is it possible ?And How?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: your question is not clear....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any method by which you can capture reference of current running activity.however There is a topActivity field defined on the RunningTaskInfo class. You can get a list of running tasks via the getRunningTasks(int) method in the ActivityManager. Traverse through that list to find the currently active task by checking the topActivity field.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I immediately go to have a try.